# SQL Query To Broad Search My Products In Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to build my user product search a bit broad. When I am performing a query in mysql its returning good result. But when I am trying to use it in my laravel site, its showing no product found.

Product name: Zero Full Sleeve Suit - The Great
It could be in any way like: Great Zero Full Suit

I want to search it by any word like: Zero Sleeve Suit Full

SQl Query for mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `pdt_products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%zero%' OR `name` LIKE '%sleeve%' OR `name` LIKE '%suit%' OR `name` LIKE '%full%';
```

This query returning some products I wanted to search by this term, and also returning some products matching partial word also.

But its not working on my laravel query:

```
elseif (count($explodeVar) < 5) {
            $products->where('name',  'like', '%'.$explodeVar[0].'%')
                   ->orWhere('name',  'like', '%'.$explodeVar[1].'%');
                   ->orWhere('name',  'like', '%'.$explodeVar[2].'%');
                   ->orWhere('name',  'like', '%'.$explodeVar[3].'%');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you go `->get()` on `$products`, what does it return?
What do you get from `dd($explodedVar)` (which is a bad name for the variable btw, you can name it something like `keywords`), because `$explodedVar` might contain some extra characters or a space.

Comment: I am getting 

`{
  "id": 4390,
  "name": "Name Of The Product",
  "slug": "slug-of-the-product",
  "sku": "SKU",
}`

Comment: $explodedVar is also working fine, if you think it's a bad variable, I  will try to consider it. I am worried about the search string ordering. I tried wildcard match by exploding them, but I think the ordering is not matching.